# Flutter App redirecting to login page everytime after logging in

Tags: api, flutter, dart, jwt

In my Flutter App, after user logs in the user is redirected to LoginPage instead of MainPage in the app. User authentication is done using JWT. All APIs are in a laravel project. I have checked all the APIs and they are working just as they should using Postman. Thanks in advance.

The following is my main.dart.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:my_app/login.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "my_app",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MainPage(),
      theme: ThemeData(
          accentColor: Colors.white70
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkLoginStatus();
  }

  checkLoginStatus() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(sharedPreferences.getString("token") == null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Evanto App", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              sharedPreferences.clear();
              sharedPreferences.commit();
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
            },
            child: Text("Log Out", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text("Main Page")),
      drawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

login.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:my_app/main.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.teal],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
        ),
        child: _isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            headerSection(),
            textSection(),
            buttonSection(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  signIn(String email, password) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map data = {
      'email': email,
      'password': password
    };
    var jsonResponse = null;
    var response = await http.post("http://my_api.com/api/auth/login", body: data);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if(jsonResponse != null) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['token']);
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      print(response.body);
    }
  }

  Container buttonSection() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 40.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: emailController.text == "" || passwordController.text == "" ? null : () {
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = true;
          });
          signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
        },
        elevation: 0.0,
        color: Colors.purple,
        child: Text("Sign In", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70)),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
      ),
    );
  }

  final TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  Container textSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: emailController,
            cursorColor: Colors.white,

            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.white70),
              hintText: "Email",
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30.0),
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            cursorColor: Colors.white,
            obscureText: true,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.white70),
              hintText: "Password",
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70)),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container headerSection() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 30.0),
      child: Text("Evanto App",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white70,
              fontSize: 40.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
void main() async {
  await StorageUtil.getInstance();
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "my_app",
      home: StorageUtil.getString("token") != null ? MainPage() : LoginPage(),
      theme: ThemeData(accentColor: Colors.white70),
    );
  }
}
```

To get access getString statically you can create a util class where you instantiate your `SharedPreferences` with a private constructor

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class StorageUtil {
  static StorageUtil _storageUtil;
  static SharedPreferences _preferences;

  static Future<StorageUtil> getInstance() async {
    if (_storageUtil == null) {
      var secureStorage = StorageUtil._();
      await secureStorage._init();
      _storageUtil = secureStorage;
    }
    return _storageUtil;
  }

  StorageUtil._();
  Future _init() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  // get string
  static String getString(String key, {String defValue = ''}) {
    if (_preferences == null) return defValue;
    return _preferences.getString(key) ?? defValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm getting this: Instance member 'getString' can't be accessed using static access.

Comment: I don't find any errors, but I'm left with a white screen this time.